# How to parse a quoted string?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string similar to this, this string is from a long HTML page source:

```
"entity_id":"1234567890"
```

I'm trying to parse the number `1234567890` like this, but the id could not be parsed:

```
var re = new Regex("\"entity_id\":\"([0 - 9] +)\"");
var match = re.Match(task.Result);

var id = match.Success ? match.Value : string.Empty;
Console.WriteLine(id);
```

Why it it's not parsed and how to fix it?

Comment: This looks a lot like a fragment from a larger JSON content.  Is this JSON?

Comment: no it's contained in a page html source

Comment: With regex: `var id = Regex.Match(s, "\"entity_id\":\"([0-9]+)\"")?.Groups[1].Value`.

Comment: good work. worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the spaces:

```
//var re = new Regex("\"entity_id\":\"([0 - 9] +)\"");
  var re = new Regex("\"entity_id\":\"([0-9]+)\"");
```

and then use

```
 var id = match.Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : string.Empty;
```

Comment: good work. works